# Using "it" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: pronouns, dummy-pronouns

> It can be difficult to talk about subjects like XXXX.

> It can be difficult to learn a new language.

> I hope it doesn't rain Today.

What does *it* means in the above sentences?
Why should we start the sentences with *it*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*It* in those sentences is called [dummy pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun): It is used without any reference to any [agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_%28grammar%29), but it is syntactically required.

The first sentence could be rephrased as "Talking about subjects like XXXX can be difficult." while the second sentence could be rephrased as "Learning a new language can be difficult." The difference between the original sentences and the one I am suggesting is the word order. With the original sentences, the first words are "It can be difficult"; that could be done to put those words in evidence.

With sentences about weather, the verb (e.g. *rain*, *snow*) is impersonal, and intransitive. Since in English the subject of a sentence is normally not implicit, *it* is used. (In English you don't normally write a sentence like "Is playing football with his friends." or "Rains.")