# In "It is raining", what does "It" refer to?

Tags: dummy-pronouns

If "it" is a noun, what is it? If instead, "it is" is the 3rd person present verb to-be, what is the subject of the sentence? (How is *it* grammatical to have a sentence consisting only of two verbs in that case?)

Comment: Whenever someone says "it is cold!" I say: no, *you* are cold, *it* is just fine!

Comment: Related question, [Using “it” at the beginning of a sentence](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5667/using-it-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence/5668#5668).

Answer (score 9):

You have asked exactly the right question.

> What is the subject of the sentence?

You know that an English sentence has to have at least a Subject and a Verb.

In the sentence *It is raining*, the Verb is easy to pick out: *is raining*, the verb *RAIN* in the present progressive construction.

But ***what*** is raining? Does the sky rain? Do the clouds rain? Does some Raingod rain? Is there anything or anybody which actually ***does*** something when rain falls? Not really.

But an English sentence ***has*** to have a Subject. So we cheat. We use ***it***. We call this kind of *it* a ***dummy***, something which we use instead of something real, like a tailor's dummy, or a ventriloquist's dummy, or a crash dummy.

***It*** in *it is raining* isn't something which actually exists: it's a dummy which only there because we have to have a Subject.

Comment: Reminds me of the TV commercial which had the sentence, "You could learn a lot from a dummy." But why do we have to have a subject? Couldn't meaningful things be said without a subject?

Comment: @nocomprende Oh, sure. <<< *That's not a sentence: it doesn't have either a subject or a verb. But that's permitted because it is understood to modify the topic of your question.* You could say simply "Rain!" ... or "Cold!" or "Cloudy!" But those don't *assert* a current fact; if we want to bring a new assertion into a discourse, we ordinarily use the sentence form to make it an assertion.

Comment: Wow! The explanation is very impressive!

Answer (score 4):

Because of the **context** of your sentence, **it** refers to **the weather**, since only the weather can **rain**.

> **It** is raining
>   **It** is snowing
>   **It** is windy
>   **It's** howling out there
>   **It's** bucketing   *(means raining extremely hard)*

can all be understood to **refer to the weather** which is usually considered **genderless**

The phrase

> **It** is hot

might elicit a response of **What is hot?** if the subject is not immediately apparent since many **different** things can have a high temperature.

Comment: So, really, the verb To Be hides the actual intent of the sentence. In the sidebar, a featured question says "Is it effective to review code in a language I don't know?" Is *what* effective? The whole construction seems very convoluted. *isn't* there a more direct way to say *it*?

Comment: The sentence refers to the weather, but *weather* isn't the antecedent of *it*, which is just a dummy subject.

Comment: @nocomprende The dummy subject allows you to place words close together that need to be close together, e.g., "effective" and "to review."  Without a dummy subject, we can ask "Is reviewing code in a language I don't know effective?"  This makes our reader wait until the end of the sentence to find out what kind of reviewing we're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

**It** (pronoun)

3. used in the normal subject position in statements about time, distance, or weather.
   "It's half past five"

*It* is a utility word. It has many uses.

Comment: Sounds recursive. I wonder how these things are said in languages that do not have the verb To Be?

Comment: The Spanish equivalent is the noun *hacer*: "Hace lloviendo."