Can we use "It varies a lot" at the beginning of a new paragraph?
Can we use "It varies a lot" at the very beginning of a sentence or a paragraph in written English? I just had a harsh debate with the part-time lecturer about whether we could use "It varies a lot" in the first clause of the first sentence of a paragraph.
Example: "It varies a lot, but I wake up around 8:30. Then I stretch my calves on the windowsill every morning. ~"
PTL (part-time lecturer) says that 'it' cannot be allowed at the beginning of a sentence because "it is a wrong start as there is no word accounting for 'it' in the front."
I think "it" in the sentence is functioning as a dummy subject, and since "I" is the subject of the second clause, there is no need to correct the "dummy subject sentence."
Who is more likely to be correct, me or PTL? And how should I find the reference literature about that specific topic?

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5667/using-it-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence?rq=1 - yes, it's a dummy pronoun. I'm not sure where your lecturer's "rule" is coming from, since even disregarding dummy pronouns, you can start a sentence with it if the context makes it clear what it refers to. ("I ordered a cheeseburger yesterday. It was really good.")

I don't think it's grammatically wrong, but I find it awkward, unless it's obvious from the context that you are talking about the time you wake up. Out of context, the reader wonders "What varies a lot?" (It sounds more natural in informal speech.)

@KateBunting - if the dummy pronoun is immediately explained, I think one can find honourable precedents.

Really, I couldn't accept her illogical grammatical sense, and that debate ended as I took my textbook and left the university classroom. That experience felt like my whole life as a tech research student writing English papers was being denied. After finding some linguistic papers for rebuttal, I may write a complaint to the university authorities.

@MaciejStachowski but your example starts off with "I ordered a cheeseburger" There is no "it" , and  in "It was really good" the pronoun clearly refers to the burger, which I suppose was the point you were making but it's not the same thing. "The time I wake up varies a lot." is, academically speaking, preferable but I wouldn't highlight the OP's choice as being "wrong"

@Mari-LouA yes, this was in response to the lecturer's blanket assertion that "it" cannot be allowed at the beginning of a sentence - to which there are obvious counterexamples that don't even need a dummy subject. But as Michael shows in the answer below, there's nothing wrong with "it" being even at the beginning of an entire book.

It sounds overly conversational here without more context: "It varies a lot, but I wake up around 8:30. Then I stretch my calves on the windowsill every morning.  Start with what it is you do rather than It varies a lot.  I understand your lecturer's objection which is not grammatical; it's stylistic. You are not texting a friend, are you? "It varies a lot could refer to" The time I wake up, and therefore it is not a dummy pronoun.

@MaciejStachowski the PTL also said " 'it' cannot be allowed at the beginning of a sentence because "it is a wrong start as there is no word accounting for 'it' in the front."" I seriously doubt the PT lecturer would have objected to your sentences "I ordered a cheeseburger yesterday. It was really good."

@MichaelHarvey I quite like your answer, would you consider "undeleting" it? I didn't upvote (not yet) it because I was hoping for a longer explanation instead of a screenshot of P&P  first page. However, the first word of the first paragraph, nay, the first word on the page is an "it" which debunks the PTL theory.

If the sentence was "It was raining", I don't see any other way of writing it without using 'It'

You (J. Moon) might reconsider this entire thing by realizing why this is not a dummy subject and why one doesn't start speaking/writing like that ex nihilo but only once a context has been established.//It was raining. is a dummy pronoun. It's funny. [can be or not be one].

@Lambie I'd rather you didn't post any comment(s) criticising me and my opinions from this moment on. Thank you

It requires some prior context.  It isn't illegal in and of itself.  It amuses me that they also started a sentence with "it" when describing why it isn't legal to do that (or at least that's how you phrased it here).  It also amuses me that I've started every sentence in this comment with "it".

@AgnishomChattopadhyay - rain was falling, the weather was wet, a shower was taking place

@Maciej While you are of course correct that it is fine to start sentences with it, and also fine to start paragraphs or even stories with dummy pronouns, your very first statement here is not correct: in the phrase “it varies a lot”, it is not a dummy pronoun and thus requires an antecedent. That is precisely why starting a paragraph or story with that phrase doesn't work well.

@JanusBahsJacquet even if we don't treat it as a dummy pronoun, you can still use inversion here the way OP does. Compare, say, "They might not be big, but mice are some of the smartest creatures on the planet." - a perfectly valid opening sentence even though it starts with a "hanging" they.

@Maciej Certainly – in that case, mice is the antecedent of it (or postcedent, to be pedantic). In the example given, though, there is no real antecedent. There is a semantic relationship between it and the statement “I get up…”, but it’s not an actual antecedent. If “I get up…” is first, the ‘stage’ is set ahead of time and we immediately understand it as referring to the situation or time of getting out of bed; but if we invert the clauses, we have neither an actual antecedent nor a set stage, and parsing it starts being too much complicated to work.

Who does the part time lecturer say cannot allow this usage? The concept of allowing or not allowing a particular way of writing is complicated.

Please show this to the lecturer. You may wish to consider complaining to the college or school authorities.


A pedantic person would have no problem saying, "That book is wrong". No matter how famous the book or the author. :-)

Austen's writing style is interesting; it was a time when the English language was changing a lot, and she came from the West of England far from the metropolitan centres. So there are a lot of idiosyncrasies and new coinages in her writing, many of which were popularized by her writing. But I think "it" is definitely fine. And Dickens also started a novel "It was the worst of times, it was the best of times" (after her).

@StuartF - yes. It was a toss-up for me between Austen and Dickens.

This usage, with the declarative content clause that a single man ...., is different than OP's.

1984 starts with "It" as well.

As, famously, does The Crow Road by Iain Banks.

And even more famously: The Tale of Two Cities, which starts with a dummy it followed by nine more in the first paragraph of Dickens' book. So Dickens beats Austen in the dummy pronoun  department.

Unfortunately, this only works as a counter-claim to the specific (and obviously untenable) claim that no sentence can ever begin with the word it under any circumstances. A literal reading of the question does yield such a claim, but I doubt it accurately represents what the lecturer actually said. More likely, they objected to the particular use of it mentioned in the question, which is fundamentally different from any of the literary examples mentioned, since the it in the example is not a dummy pronoun and does indeed lack an antecedent.

I actually deleted this answer, because various people had made me feel embarrassed about it, but @Mari-LouA asked me to reinstate it, and the votes keep piling up. Vox populis, vox Dei, or something like that. I wasn't altogether serious about it in the first place.

Am I missing something? Where is "It varies a lot" in that text?

@SteveIves - in which text? If you mean my answer, it attempts to answer the query in the body of the question by the OP (rather than the one in the title), namely, 'Is my lecturer right to say that 'it' cannot be allowed at the beginning of a sentence?'.

The construction needs to have two clauses joined by but.  This would be analogous to "It varies a lot but..":  "It may take a while, but people usually come to their senses." The construction is not at all uncommon.  Austen's sentence could be reordered: "That  a single man in possession of a good fortune must be in need of a wife is a truth universally acknowledged."  "It" is a proxy for the declarative that- clause.

@MichaelHarvey OK - so it's an example of something similar but not exactly the same phrase. It made me reconsider my opinion in as much as this example works, and I was wondering why. I think an almost 'lecturing' type writing style can carry this off. I don't think it works in conversation (which your example isn't). I agree though that it shows you can use 'it' at the beginning of a sentence.

It is perfectly fine to begin a sentence with "it". It is not at all difficult for native speakers to understand such sentences, which ultimately is the goal of most communication anyway. It turns out that many of these "grammatical rules" are not rules at all, but only describe some of the simpler uses of English. It sounds like your lecturer may not have had thorough exposure to the many flexible uses of this word, and the English language as a whole. It is a shame that you're having difficulty convincing your lecturer of this.

It's not something a native English speaker would say unless you had been talking about the time you wake up before this sentence.

I don't think the instructor was referring to all uses of "it" at the start of a sentence, but only this particular type of use.

I have to disagree with @SteveIves.  A native speaker could indeed begin a sentence in that manner, perhaps with a "Ya know".  "Ya know, it varies a lot, but I usually ...".   The meaning of "it varies a lot" won't be immediately clear, but as soon as the second clause is uttered, the import of "it varies a lot" would be understood by the listener.  Speakers in casual conversation do not alway "package" their utterances optimally.  The sentence would be fully understandable nonetheless. 50% of oral communication is listening.

Without more context (preceding sentences) and out of the blue, this sentence:
"It varies a lot, but I wake up around 8:30. Then I stretch my calves on the windowsill every morning." spoken as a first sentence or written as such is stylistically poor. It has nothing to do with grammar per se. It has to do with style. In that sentence, "it" is not a dummy pronoun.

Why is it not a dummy pronoun?

Because: the it pronoun replaces this implied phrase:  the time I wake up.
" It [he time I wake up] varies a lot, but I wake up around 8:30. Then I stretch my calves on the windowsill every morning." It is fine in normal conversation:
Q: What time do you wake up, Amalia?
A: It varies a lot, but I wake up around 8:30. Then I stretch my calves on the windowsill every morning."
So, your PTL is right if there is no previous context like this:
Waking up can be annoying or fun. It varies a lot in my case but I wake up etc.
OR, with a dummy pronoun:
It is true that waking up can be fun or not. Etc.

Dummy pronoun

A dummy pronoun is used when a particular verb argument (or preposition) is nonexistent (it could also be unknown, irrelevant, already understood, or otherwise "not to be spoken of directly") but when a reference to the argument (a pronoun) is nevertheless syntactically required. For example, in the phrase "It is obvious that the violence will continue", it is a dummy pronoun, not referring to any agent. Unlike a regular pronoun of English, it cannot be replaced by any noun phrase.[citation needed]
The term dummy pronoun refers to the function of a word in a particular sentence, not a property of individual words. For example, it in the example from the previous paragraph is a dummy pronoun, but it in the sentence "I bought a sandwich and ate it" is a referential pronoun (referring to the sandwich).
Here is a very famous quote with 10 dummy its, the first paragraph of the Dickens' novel:

“It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age
of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief,
it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of light, it was
the season of darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter
of despair.” ― Charles Dickens, A Tale of Two Cities


That is the first sentence in the book.

Is "stylistically poor" not entirely subjective?

@Omegastick Well, it isn't objective. We answer as subjects, not objects. But my argument holds water.

If the lecturer's objection is that we don't know what "it" refers to, this might not be the best counterexample, as Dickens spends the next five lines explaining exactly what "it" is.

@ray But that doesn't mean the "its" aren't dummy.

Good answer. There's no right or wrong here, but there is good and bad (and yes, that's subjective). Remember that it's a mark of good novelists that they constantly give you an incentive to read on: you want to find out what "it" is that they speak of. But it takes more than an anticipatory pronoun to achieve that.

@MichaelKay Thank you for such a cogent comment! :)

As others have said, this particular "it" (which is not very similar to the "It was" starting certain famous novels) sounds a bit strange unless there was at least some preceding context. But there is absolutely no reason why the preceding context can't be in a different paragraph. For example, it is perfectly reasonable for the answer to a question to start with "It varies a lot, but...", and here you absolutely should start a new paragraph because the speaker has changed.

Your sentence is perfectly idiomatic and something like it would be spoken tens of thousands of times a day throughout the English-speaking world.
Just Google "it varies a lot but" for examples.
A long-winded paraphrase would be something like:

{ What I'm about to say varies considerably  }  -- I wake up (usually) around 8:30...

It is conversational. It is a kind of concession:

Although it varies from day to day, I usually wake up around 8:30AM.

"It" refers to the declaration in the main clause.
What is weird about your utterance is the second sentence, which goes on to say that every morning  the speaker does a stretching exercise. Then is a bit odd as a transition between a statement about The Varying and one about The Unvarying. One might expect but instead.
P.S. In a written composition, if you wish to say something like that, the text should be in a casual, conversational register (and, of course, you'd use that register only when it is deemed suitable).

It’s interesting that placing the it in a subordinate clause like this makes it perfectly natural even as an opener. But as stated in the question, it is clumsy and unnatural. “It varies, but I usually wake up at…” works fine as an answer, but not very well as an opening line; “although it varies, I usually wake up at…” works fine as either. When the pronoun is in a subordinate clause, we are more prepared to expect its antecedent to follow it instead of preceding it.

This would be a very odd way to begin a sentence unless the speaker had been asked what time they wake up, or waking up time was clearly the subject of an existing conversation.

@JanusBahsJacquet I would include this kind of structure under the "Your-mileage-may-vary" type.  Your mileage may vary, but I find Itch-b-Gone works far better than Scratch-Away.   The opening clause is a "speech-act" adjunct and "it" refers to what is being declared in the subsequent clause.

@SteveIves  OP's example about how they wake up is a poor example when discussing "paragraphs" so I took it as merely a structural example and discarded the content.

Or It varies a lot, but the elevated train is how I commute to work most days.  It can be understood as a qualifier of the declaration made in the subsequent clause.  It's informal. I've heard this sort of thing a gazillion times from AmE speakers, of which I am one.   If the text you're composing is equally informal, it's fine  as an opener, even though it is somewhat in medias res.

@Tim ‘Your mileage may vary’ seems different to me, with an explicit subject that doesn’t require an antecedent. Even so, I would also consider your mileage example to be odd if it weren’t already established that the topic at hand is something about itches. Less awkward than the example in the question, but it still seems an unnatural way to start ex nihilo.

@JanusBahsJacquet I think you and Steve are both not giving enough weight to my remark that it is  conversational, and in informal conversation this sort of thing is not unusual ("odd") at all.  It happens all the time.  Casual speech is often messy. That said, unless the written text (OP mentions a "paragraph") is itself in a casual, conversational register, this kind of vagueness (sloppiness, even) of reference would be inappropriate. It varies a lot, but the elevated train is how I commute to work most days is perfectly idiomatic conversational AmE.

Normally the conversation won't have been about baseball or football seconds earlier, so that the sentence in its entirety would be a non-sequitur.

@Tim Absolutely – within the context of a spoken conversation, it works fine, because there you have exactly that type of stage-setting that makes it work. But the way the question is phrased, talking about starting paragraphs in written English, makes me think that context is explicitly not what’s being asked about. It kind of feels like J.Moon is asking, “Can I do this in writing with no previous context?”, and your answer is, “Yes, but only in speech with previous context”.

@JanusBahsJacquet I will clarify with a P.S.  I said "conversational", which doesn't rule out written compositions in the way that "used only in conversation" would.

@TimR I can't imagine a single example - conversational or not - where someone would say something like this.

@SteveIves  I hear and read that construction every day.   I could cite many many many of them. Here's one: https://www.threads.net/@austinkuchar/post/CueoF4CuwaV   Just Google "it varies a lot but"

I searched the web - nothing the same where someone starts talking about a new subject with that construction at the start of the sentence. Your  brain instantly says "What varies a lot?" and it throws you off until the speaker clarifies themselves.
I don't think that you are giving enough consideration to the fact that it's not the phrase "It varies a lot" that is being debated, but its use at the beginning of a sentence when the subject of the sentence is not already under discussion.

@TimR Hmm - looking at the highest rated answer here, I can see that in a text-book/lecturing scenario that you could get away with this E.g. the intro of a book on some difficult subject: "It varies a lot, but the general public generally believe that...". I can't see it ever being used in conversation.

Other people have discussed the usage of dummy pronouns.  I’ll bring up another, subtle point..
“It varies” is more formal than “a lot,” so I would recommend rewriting the sentence for a more consistent tone.  “It varies considerably,” or “It varies from day to day,” would work better in formal writing.
